# How to query a single item based on its name in a sql database and return cursor?

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor, sqliteopenhelper

I have a database with all food items. I want to search the database for a variable food item and get its Cursor. Let us take food item = Oranges as an example. The following line gives the correct result when typed in terminal.

```
SELECT * from food WHERE item = 'Oranges'
```

To implement it I made a method called getOneItem in the class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper as below.

```
public Cursor getOneItem(String itemName) {
    return myDataBase.query(TABLE, null, C_NAME+" = " +itemName , null, null, null, null);

}
```

But when the method is called I get the error "No such column: Oranges, while compiling

```
SELECT * from table WHERE item = Oranges
```

Why is the computer searching for a column called Oranges and not searching inside the column for Oranges?

When I modified the method to:

```
public Cursor getOneItem(String itemName) {
    return myDataBase.query(TABLE, null, C_NAME+" = '" +itemName +"'", null, null, null, null);

}
```

I get CursorIndexOutOfBoundException, Index -1 requested with size of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second argument should not be null... Specify the columns that u need to display..

```
   return  myDataBase.query( TABLE, new String[] {
                    C_NAME
                    }, 
                    C_NAME + "= ?" , 
                    new String[] { itemName }, ,         
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
```

Comment: btw i changed the second argument back to null, as I wanted all the columns (Setting it to null is supposed to do that). It still works. I had problems quering columns. The third and fourth argument syntax was required.

Comment: oh it was useful. thanks :) <i did not mean to be ungrateful>